# facing getvibrantcolor(int) palette cannot be applied to () in androidx

Tags: android, androidx, palette

Hello I am facing `getvibrantcolor(int) palette cannot be applied to ()` error after migrating code to Androidx before migrating it was working good. please help me to resolve this issue.

following is my code where i am initializing and using Palette with Bitmap  -

```
Bitmap photo = setupPhoto(getIntent().getIntExtra("photo", R.drawable.xyz));
colorize(photo);

private void colorize(Bitmap photo) {
    Palette palette = Palette.generate(photo);
    applyPalette(palette);
}

private void applyPalette(Palette palette) {
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(palette.getDarkMutedColor().getRgb()));

    TextView titleView = findViewById(R.id.title);
    titleView.setTextColor(palette.getVibrantColor().getRgb());

    TextView descriptionView = findViewById(R.id.description);
    descriptionView.setTextColor(palette.getLightVibrantColor().getRgb());

    colorRipple(R.id.info, palette.getDarkMutedColor().getRgb(),
            palette.getDarkVibrantColor().getRgb());
    colorRipple(R.id.star, palette.getMutedColor().getRgb(),
            palette.getVibrantColor().getRgb());

    View infoView = findViewById(R.id.information_container);
    infoView.setBackgroundColor(palette.getLightMutedColor().getRgb());

    AnimatedPathView star = findViewById(R.id.star_container);
    star.setFillColor(palette.getVibrantColor().getRgb());
    star.setStrokeColor(palette.getLightVibrantColor().getRgb());
}
```

Following is error image - 
[image]

following is app build.gridle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx.info"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: for test case try `int white = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white);
....palette.getVibrantColor(white);`

Comment: not working it saying cannot resolved symbol`getVibrantColor`

Comment: check first answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/palette/graphics/Palette#getVibrantColor(int)):

> public int getVibrantColor (int defaultColor)

So you need to pass in a default color that should be returned if no vibrant color is available:

```
// Use whatever default color you want
int defaultColor = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black);
titleView.setTextColor(palette.getVibrantColor(defaultColor));
```

Comment: can you please explain how i can pass default color i tried `getDarkMutedColor(R.color.photo_tint).getRgb())` but it was giving error to `.getRgb()`

Comment: You get an int back that you can pass directly to `setBackgroundColor`, you don't need any `getRgb()` method at all

Comment: facing `error: method getVibrantColor in class Palette cannot be applied to given types;` see https://tmpfiles.org/download/46026/Screenshot2020-04-22at10.33.09AM.png

Comment: Please edit your question with additional details, error messages, and your updated code.